# Help with Big O and Big Omega problem.

Tags: functions, algorithms

this is a homework problem:

1) $$ \text{Let }f(n) = n^2+5000 \text{ and } g(n) = 5(n^2) + 100.\text{ Prove formally that }f(n) = \theta (g(n)) $$

My attempt:

a)Prove f(n) is $ O(g(n)) $:  When $ n > \sqrt{980} $, $ n^2 + 5000 < 5n^2+100 $

b)Prove f(n) is $ \Omega(g(n)) $: When $ n < \sqrt{980} $ , $n^2 + 5000 > 5n^2+100 $

Therefor, f(n) = $ \Theta(g(n)) $

My reasoning is that if a function is Big Theta of another function, it is both Big O and Big Omega of it too. What I am not sure of is if I actually proved that f(n) is O(g(n)) and Omega(g(n)). And what would be C1, and C2? I am sorry if my question is confusing or if this is supposed to be obvious.

Edit: Made a mistake while copying, fixed it, sorry. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove $f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$, take $c=1,n_0=40$, then $f(n)=n^2+5000<1(5n^2+100)=c*g(n)\forall n\geq n_0$

To prove $g(n)$ is $O(f(n))$, take $c=5,n_0=1$, then $g(n)=5n^2+100<5(n^2+5000)=c*f(n)\forall n\geq n_0$

Comment: Do you mind looking at the problem again? (I copied it wrong the first time)

Comment: editing done :)

Comment: Thank you, why n_0 = 40? Also, what is wrong with $ \sqrt{980} $?

Comment: i wanted a large enough integer so i tried $n_0=40$ if it satisfy the inequality and it does.

Comment: $n^2+5000<5n^2+100\implies 4n^2>4900\implies n^2>1225\implies n>35$. For $n_0=\sqrt{980}$, these inequality doesn't hold for $c=1$, may be for some other $c$, it can take $n_0=\sqrt{980}$

Comment: So if I find a $c$ that holds for $ n_0= \sqrt{980}$ then my proofs would be correct?

Comment: No, for $\Omega$ part, you should find $c$ such that $f(n)>c*g(n)\forall n>n_0=\sqrt{980}$

Comment: Wouldn't that also mean that $n_0$ for the $\Omega$ part can be equal to 40?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: One last question, if $n_0$ = 40, does that mean c = 1 in the $\Omega$ part too? Thank you for everything, by the way.

Comment: since for $c=1$, inequality holds for $n_0=40$, so you can take this pair.No problem with that

Answer (score 3):

For every $n$, $\color{red}{1}\cdot f(n)\leqslant g(n)\leqslant\color{red}{5}\cdot f(n)$, hence $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$.

**New version of the question:** 

For every $n$, $\color{red}{\frac1{50}}\cdot f(n)\leqslant g(n)\leqslant\color{red}{5}\cdot f(n)$, hence $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$.

Comment: Okay you are going to have to explain this a bit to me. Too prove $ \Theta $ don't I have to find some C1 and C2 for which C1 g(n) <= f(n) <= C2g(n)?

Comment: they are equivalent

Comment: Do you mind looking at the problem again? (I copied it wrong the first time)

Comment: Chase: I did. $ $

Answer (score 1):

One more way:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2+5000}{5n^2+100} \geq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ n^2}{105n^2}=\frac{1}{105}>0
$$
since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{5000}{105n^2}=0$. Hence, $f(n)=\Omega(g(n))$. At the same time, 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ 5001n^2}{5n^2}=\frac{5001}{5}>0
$$
hence, $f(n)=O(g(n))$. Combining these two gets the result for $\Theta(n)$.

Comment: Can you point me to a resource that can explain how to prove these things formally with limits? I'm interested.

Comment: The best I can think of is the last chapter on asymptotics in $\textit{Concrete Mathematics}$ by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik

Comment: Thank you! I'll check them out.

Comment: You are welcome